# (Mac OS) No matching distribution found for ray

Tags: macos, pip, installation, ray

so I've been trying to pip install ray in a conda environment. Here's the code I use:

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org -U ray
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ray (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for ray
```

I tried this on a friend's mac, and it worked perfectly fine. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have Python 3.8 and [`ray` doesn't currently provide wheels for 3.8](https://pypi.org/project/ray/0.8.0/#files), only for 3.5-3.7, and no source code.

Downgrade to Python 3.7.

Comment: Thanks, this was driving me crazy

Comment: @ASimpleProgrammer Use newer version: https://pypi.org/project/ray/1.13.0/#files — any wheel you want, Python 3.6-3.10.

Comment: I actually keep getting this error when installing in a docker container, and I don't know why.

Comment: @ASimpleProgrammer You should ask a separate question naming your platform (inside Docker), OS, Python version, and showing the full text of the error message copy/pasted from the terminal and formatted. Also the 1st thing to try is to upgrade `pip`.